# Determinate position properties (e.g. land or water) in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I would like to know if it is possible to determinate position properties (e.g. land or water) in Leaflet as I wasn't able to find any helpful information using a simple search.

Comment: That's a point-in-polygon query against a coastline database (such as https://osmdata.openstreetmap.de/data/coastlines.html ). You should think about what database you want to use, since the results will differ.

Comment: Thank you for you help. I decided to convert the shapeline file to geojson via shapefile-js and then use @turf/boolean-point-in-polygon on it. Please write this as a question so I can accept it as an answer.

Comment: @IvanSanchez can you please add this as an answer?

Comment: @virtumonde why don't you post your solution as an answer? I'd definitely upvote it.

Comment: @Script47 added but it's not more detailed than my comment because I don't remember the exact code I used at that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the point and query an API service called [IsItWater.com](https://isitwater.com) which will let you check if the coordinate is over land or water. It is based on OpenStreetMap data.

### Request

```
curl 'https://isitwater-com.p.rapidapi.com/?latitude=41.9029192&longitude=-70.2652276&rapidapi-key=YOUR-X-RAPIDAPI-KEY'
```

### Response

```
{
    "water": true,
    "latitude": 41.9029192,
    "longitude": -70.2652276
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I decided to convert the shapeline file to geojson via shapefile-js and then use @turf/boolean-point-in-polygon on it.

Comment: Do you remember how you dealt with parsing the massive geojson file?

Comment: @Script47 I just remember now that I didn't use shapefile-js because it was too inefficient but I don't remember what I've used instead. I'll add a comment is somehow I would recall the name of the software.